# Get calling/client Assembly in portable area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have an action being executed inside of a portable area that needs to get information about the `Assembly` that called it. The portable area is in project `Core` and is referenced by client app `Client`.

`GetAssembly` and `GetExecutingAssembly` both return the `Core` assembly:

```
// Both are Core
assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(GetType());
assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
```

My next thought was to use `GetCallingAssembly`, but that brings back `Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly.`

```
assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
```

The only other option is `GetEntryAssembly`, which is just null:

```
assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
```

What I want to do is get a reference to the `Client` assembly using the built-in framework. Obviously, I could use some fancy dependency injection or some other less sophisticated method to get that information to this action; however, I'm wondering if there's a better built-in way to do this.

**Clarification**: What I'm trying to get here is version information of the client Assembly. I want each client to have access to a `VersionInfo` partial that lives in the `Core` area and adds build version information to a rendered page. So, the action in `Core` needs to know the Assembly that called it so that it can reflect out the version info.

Comment: Can you provide some context? What information does the portable area need from the assembly that uses it? DI/IoC sounds like the best solution so far, but it doesn't have to be "fancy".

Comment: Added a clarification - I agree that DI doesn't sound like a terrible solution; I was just hoping there was some magical thing already built in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much effort and many tears, I've determined that DI is going to be the best way to do this. Why?

**Some Info on Portable Areas**
After some research and observation, it appears that portable areas run in their own sub-instance of MVC. My attempt to call a partial view from my portable area lives in the view of my client application:

```
@Html.Action("Versions", "Core")
```

If I pull out a stacktrace at the `Version` Action in `Core`, I get:

> Core.Versions()
>   at System.Web.Mvc...
>   at System.Web.Mvc...
>   at ASP._Page_Views_Shared_Layouts__Base_cshtml.Execute()
>   at System.Web.Mvc...
>   at ...

Since all of the controller code in my Client application has already executed, there's not even a reference to that assembly in the stack trace any longer. I also tried adding an `Assembly` arg to the `Versions` action, a la:

```
@Html.Action("Versions", "Core", new { assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() })
```

but the result from that is `App_Web_xq4cmhcy`, obviously a generated assembly.

So, really the only option left is to add a DI container that gets initialized in the Global.asax of every client application with the executing assembly, which can then be read by the Core method.